# ImageButton.setImageResource getting blur/pixeled

Tags: android, image

i dont know why, i tested for 24, 36 and 48dp png icons from iconfinder and https://materialdesignicons.com

but they keep showing some kind of pixels around the image, i have a LG G4

i dont know if you guy will see it but look:

[image]

what i see when device is in my hand:

[image]

the images are so "strange" not beautiful =/ not matter if its 24dp 36dp or 48dp they just change the size in the screen but the pixeled border is still visible

my code to set the imageres:

```
status.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
```

the code of the ImageButton .xml

```
<ImageButton

    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/download"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width & height to "wrap content".

```
android:id="@+id/status"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:src="@drawable/download"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Setting the width to "wrap_content" but height to "fill_parent" will keep the original image size in width but will take all available space in height.